# Proxy entire url path to haproxy from nginx

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, haproxy

I have nginx in entry point to server. which handle SSL connection and send `HTTP` request in `/api/v1/` to HAproxy for balancing.
this is my nginx config:

```
    location /api/v1/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8585/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

}
```

and HAproxy config:

```
frontend haproxy_entry
    bind *:8585
    mode http
    log global
    acl is_api url_beg /api/v1/
    use_backend api if is_api
```

the problem I have is that I should pass `/api/v1/` path twice. if I request `https://servername.com/api/v1/` haproxy would not handle this properly but for :`https://servername.com/api/v1/api/v1/` it's ok. how can i fix this?

Comment: Your Nginx reverse proxy is stripping off `/api/v1/`. Are you saying that it should pass the request transparently? If so, just remove the trailing `/` from the `proxy_pass` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `proxy_pass` statement includes an optional URI which is used to modify the URL before passing it upstream.

In your question, the `proxy_pass` statement includes a URI of `/`, which in conjunction with the `location` value, causes the `/api/v1/` part of the original URL to be substituted for `/`.

For example: `https://example.com/api/v1/foo` is translated to `http://127.0.0.1:8585/foo`.

It seems that you do not need this. To turn off the feature, simply remove the URI part.

For example:

```
location /api/v1/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8585;
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.